# Was Egypt inherited by the Jews according to the Koran?

Tags: quran, tafseer, bani-israel

> So We removed them from gardens and springs, and treasures and
> honorable station. Thus. And We caused to inherit it the Children of
> Israel. ([Ash-Shu'ara [26] : 57-59](https://quran.com/26/57-59))

> How much they left behind of gardens and springs. And crops and noble sites. And comfort wherein they were amused. Thus. And We caused to inherit it another people. ([Ad-Dukhan [44] : 25-28](https://quran.com/44/25-28))

It says here that the sons of Israel received the Egyptian lands. But they came out of Egypt and went to Canaan. So how could they get these lands?

> And We took the Children of Israel across the sea; then they came upon
> a people intent in devotion to [some] idols of theirs. They [the
> Children of Israel] said, "O Moses, make for us a god just as they
> have gods." He said, "Indeed, you are a people behaving ignorantly.
> ([Al-A'raf [7] : 138](https://quran.com/7/138))

Comment: [Origin of the Jews](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/225721/he-is-asking-about-the-origin-of-the-jews) by IslamQA has a well-explained history of Jews.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement the answer by @TheZ, the following explanations are also possible:

- The Bani Israel could have temporarily returned to Egypt after the drowning of Pharaoh, before continuing their journey towards Syria. This has been claimed in some traditions recorded by the exegetes, and this is also one of the possible interpretations of another verse 2:61:

  > اهبطوا مصرا فإن لكم ما سألتم
  >
  > Go into 'Egypt' and indeed, you will have what you have asked
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 2:61](https://quran.com/2/61?translations=20)</sup>
- It is possible that it means only the treasures i.e. the movable items that the Bani Israel took with them when leaving Egypt. This is present in the Torah:

  > Every woman is to ask her neighbor and any woman living in her house for articles of silver and gold and for clothing, which you will put on your sons and daughters. And so you will plunder the Egyptians.”
  >
  > <sup>— [Exodus 3:22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+3%3A22&version=NIV)</sup>

  > The Israelites did as Moses instructed and asked the Egyptians for articles of silver and gold and for clothing. The Lord had made the Egyptians favorably disposed toward the people, and they gave them what they asked for; so they plundered the Egyptians.
  >
  > <sup>— [Exodus 12:35-36](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=exodus+12%3A35-36&version=NIV)</sup>

  And some exegetes have also linked this to the items mentioned Quranic verse:

  > حملنا أوزارا من زينة القوم
  >
  > we were made to carry burdens from the ornaments of the people [of Pharaoh]
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 20:87](https://quran.com/20/87?translations=20)</sup>
- It is possible that "springs and gardens"  means those which are present in Palestine \ Syria as this area was part of the Egyptian Kingdom or was its vassal, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Kingdom_of_Egypt).
- It is possible that the Egyptians lost their wealth and the Bani Israel gained (other) wealth and properties **similar** the Egyptians. It is not necessary that they gained control over the exact same properties which had previously been owned by the Egyptians.

And there are also other possible interpretations.

Comment: Pharaoh was not taken out of Palestine. And the verse speaks precisely about the place of honor where the Pharaoh lived. Then how can it be Palestine\Syria?

Answer (score 1):

Allah says in other verses:

> And We caused the people who had been oppressed to inherit the eastern regions of the land and the western ones, which We had blessed. And the good word of your Lord was fulfilled for the Children of Israel because of what they had patiently endured. And We destroyed [all] that Pharaoh and his people were producing and what they had been building. (7:137)

> And We wanted to confer favor upon those who were oppressed in the land and make them leaders and make them inheritors And establish them in the land and show Pharaoh and [his minister] Haman and their soldiers through them that which they had feared. (28:5-6)

Allah says he caused Bani Israil to inherit power and control in the Holy Land, not particularly Egypt, because He says "the eastern and western regions of the land which we had blessed."

It is reported from many of the mufassiroon that this refers to Greater Syria because that is the land Allah has blessed.

This is most likely a reference to the reigns of Dawud and Sulaiman (AS) in which the children of Israil would hold great power on earth.

The verse "And We caused to inherit it the Children of Israel" can refer to the specific land of Egypt or it could refer to gardens, springs, treasures, and high stations like what Pharaoh used to have.

It is possible Sulaiman and Dawud (AS) also held control over Egypt in the first interpretation.

If their reigns did not include Egypt, then it means they would get those things in their kingdoms in Palestine, not necessarily the ones from Egypt.

And Allah knows best.